# Plot levels as series

Tags: r, plot, grouping

I have a data set that looks like this:

```
id      factor  H1  H2  H3  H4  H5  H6
434543  lev3    0.8 0.7 0.7 0.5 0.6 0.8
434544  lev2    0.5 0.7 0.9 0.7 0.7 0.1
434545  lev3    0.7 0.7 0.8 0.5 0.7 0.7
434546  lev2    0.4 0.6 0.5 0.8 0.7 0.2
434547  lev3    0.6 0.7 0.8 0.8 0.8 0.7
434548  lev2    0.7 0.7 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.4
434549  lev2    0.8 0.8 0.8 0.7 0.6 0.5
434550  lev1    0.3 0.3 0.4 0.3 0.4 0.5
434551  lev1    0.0 0.3 0.4 0.3 0.2 0.4
434552  lev3    0.6 0.8 0.8 0.8 0.6 0.7
434553  lev2    0.6 0.8 0.5 0.2 0.5 0.8
```

I'd like to plot the mean and SD for a level at each time point (H1...H6), but draw a continuous line through the means, not bar plots. What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: very interesting question. Even the first step, i.e. producing the mean/sd for each level and for each timepoint H1..6 without using loops will be pretty tricky!! Maybe some 2 nested calls of tapply/sapply/mapply? But I cannot figure how. For the plot part, look at `plotCI` from package plotrix - it does exactly the type of plot you want. You can do a line plot with CI whiskers (representing SD) with it.

Answer (score 5):

Here's one way to do it with the excellent `ggplot2` package.

```
require(ggplot2)
require(reshape)

# Load data
data = read.table('data.txt', header=T)

# Format data
data = melt(data, id.vars=c('id', 'factor'), variable_name='time')
data$time = as.numeric(gsub('H(.+)', '\\1', data$time))

# Function to summarize y at each x
getband <- function(y.in){
  ymax = mean(y.in) + sd(y.in)
  ymin = mean(y.in) - sd(y.in)
  data.frame(ymax, ymin)
}

# Plot
dev.new(width=5, height=4)
qplot(time, value, group=factor, geom='point', color=factor, fill=factor, data=data) + 
  stat_summary(color=0, fun.data=getband, geom='ribbon', alpha=0.2) +
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom='line')
```

[image]

Comment: That looks really good! Pretty much exactly what I was looking for. I will try this with my real data.

Comment: @fletch Great! If you want to reduce the overplotting, you can also check out the [`position_jitter`](http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/position_jitter.html) option.

Comment: *Error: could not find function "melt"* -- I've added `require (reshape)` at the start of your script.